# How do you calculate the file slack in file system?

Tags: filesystems

How do you calculate the file slack?

For example:

File system: FAT 16
Drive size: 1.6 GB
Cluster: 32kB

A text file with a size of 150,000 bytes is created. So how do you count the file slack?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileSize / cluster size (in bytes) = # clusters needed.

If (FileSize modulo cluster size in bytes <> 0), add 1 additional cluster needed.

"File slack" = (Clusters needed * 1024) - FileSize

So, for your example:

```
32 * 1024 = 32768

150000 / 32768 = 4 clusters
150000 mod 32768 = 18928 = 1 additional cluster
4 + 1 clusters needed = 5 clusters needed
5 * 32768 = 163840 - 150000 file size = 13840 slack bytes
```

Note that, even though disk drives are given in 1KB = 1000 bytes, the cluster sizes are based on 1024 bytes per KB, so you need to use that in your calculations.